# History command in ksh not able to use

Tags: command-history, ksh

I am using the ksh shell. I am not getting any impact of these following commands. It is executing without any error but it is not giving the proper results.

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

Use the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow to view the previous command and press enter to execute it.

Type `!!` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> from the command line.

Type `!-1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> from the command line.

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will display the previous command, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute it.

Basically I am not to do anything other than basic history command.

Comment: So what happens when you do this? What did you expect to happen? What is not working as expected? Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: For the information of all.. I am new to UNIX and Linux. I dont know why this question has been treated as not real.. Strange..

Comment: Look below the question: “It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete (…) and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form”. Edit your question to answer my clarification requests, and we can reopen it.

Comment: Why is it difficult to tell what is being asked here? just because you guys don't know enough about the topic and maybe should not try to reply then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you find these commands here: [how to find result of last command](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/how-to-find-result-of-last-executed-command-on-linux-QTN_154922.htm)?  Do you realize that is not a correct answer?  Do you realize it's talking about `bash`, not `ksh`?

To answer the question you asked:

Which version of `ksh` do you have?  You can find out by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, or by running `echo $KSH_VERSION`.

Why do you think these actions will work?  `!!` and `!-1` are for `bash`, `zsh`, and `csh`, not for `ksh`.

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to do anything, ensure you are using `emacs` editing mode by running `set -o emacs`.

For making the up arrow key work, there are several Google results.  Try e.g. this one [Make Arrow and Delete keys work in Korn Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623256/make-arrow-and-delete-keys-work-in-korn-shell-command-line), which says how to do it using the `alias` command.

Comment: Thanks for this.. I was new to linux and unix world. so I was struggling to articulate this question.. Now I am learning the Linux... Now I have understood these things..  Nw it seems simple.. anyhow thanks for your answer @mikel

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that depends on the particular `ksh` implementation. For `pdksh`, for example, the history is enabled by default and is not stored in a file. For some UNIX `ksh` implementation it requires `HISTFILE` to be set to enable history. You may try setting it, or check your particular `ksh` implementation's manual.

Also, depending on the implementation you will or will not be able to use up arrow and other fancy ways to access previous commands. Sometimes you will only have `emacs` or `vi` mode and will be able to scroll through history with respective editor's commands.

And just to add, `HISTTIMEFORMAT` looks more like a `bash` extension…